# TextEdittingController, I'm not able to check the input if it greater or lesser

Tags: flutter, dart

The value I'm getting from the User, I'm not able to put If statement at texteditingcontroller.

I want to check if the value that the user provides in txtControllerD1 is greater than 0 and less than 100 and then pass the value in tflite model, and more I want to create a dropdown for txtControllerD2 containing male and female if the user select male then the value be 1 and if the female is selected value be 1 and than pass it in model.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:prediciton_model/common_widgets/predictionInput.dart';
import 'package:tflite_flutter/tflite_flutter.dart';


class PredModel extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PredModelState createState() => _PredModelState();
}

class _PredModelState extends State<PredModel> {
  TextEditingController txtControllerD1 = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController txtControllerD2 = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController txtControllerD3 = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController txtControllerD4 = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController txtControllerD5 = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController txtControllerD6 = TextEditingController();

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  var predValue = "";
  bool resetStatus = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    predValue = "click predict button";
  }

  Future<void> predData() async {
    //get input from form and predict using tflite model
   
    final interpreter = await Interpreter.fromAsset(
        'heart_disease_prediction.tflite');

    var input = [
      [

        int.parse(txtControllerD1.text),
        int.parse(txtControllerD2.text),
        int.parse(txtControllerD3.text),
        int.parse(txtControllerD4.text),
        int.parse(txtControllerD5.text),
        int.parse(txtControllerD6.text)
      ]
    ];
    var output = List.filled(1 * 1, 0).reshape([1, 1]);
    print(output);
    interpreter.run(input, output);
    print(output);

    this.setState(() {
      predValue = output[0].toString();
    });
    // }
    // } catch (e) {}
  }

  // ignore: missing_return
  String fieldvalidator(txt) {
    if (!resetStatus) {
      if (txt.length < 1) {
        return "Required Field";
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }
  }

  void resetData() {
    try {
      _formKey.currentState.reset();
      txtControllerD1.clear();
      txtControllerD2.clear();
      txtControllerD3.clear();
      txtControllerD4.clear();
      txtControllerD5.clear();
      txtControllerD6.clear();

      resetStatus = true;
      setState(() {
        predValue = "click predict button";
      });
    } catch (e) {}
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
        title: Center(
          child: Text(
            "Heart Disease Prediction",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 24,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(
                "Fill all feilds to get prediction.",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
                child: Form(
                    key: _formKey,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        PredictionInput.predictionInputField(
                            val: "AGE",
                            controller: txtControllerD1,
                            inputvalidator: fieldvalidator),
                        PredictionInput.predictionInputField(
                            val: "Gender",
                            controller: txtControllerD2,
                            inputvalidator: fieldvalidator),
                        PredictionInput.predictionInputField(
                            val: "Chest Pain",
                            controller: txtControllerD3,
                            inputvalidator: fieldvalidator),
                        PredictionInput.predictionInputField(
                            val: "Blood Pressure",
                            controller: txtControllerD4,
                            inputvalidator: fieldvalidator),
                        PredictionInput.predictionInputField(
                            val: "Cholesterol Level",
                            controller: txtControllerD5,
                            inputvalidator: fieldvalidator),
                        PredictionInput.predictionInputField(
                            val: "Heart Rate",
                            controller: txtControllerD6,
                            inputvalidator: fieldvalidator),
                      ],
                    )),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 12),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  MaterialButton(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 15),
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    child: Text(
                      "predict",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                    ),
                    onPressed: predData,//_validateUserInput(
                        //txtControllerD1.text),
                  ),
                  MaterialButton(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 15),
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    child: Text(
                      "reset",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                    ),
                    onPressed: resetData,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 12),
              Text(
                "Predicted value :  $predValue ",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 23),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }      
}

    Here is predictionInput.dart
   ----------------------------

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class PredictionInput {
  static Widget predictionInputField(
      {String val, TextEditingController controller, Function inputvalidator}) {
    return (TextFormField(
      autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
      controller: controller,
      inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
      maxLength: 5,
      decoration: InputDecoration(label: Text(val), counterText: ""),
      validator: inputvalidator,
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `int.parse` will throw an exeption/error when it parse a non-number string, you need a `try-catch` block on each parse to do it for manual or using `int.tryParse` insteads,`int.tryParse` will return `null` when it can't parse a tring to a number, you can do it like this.

```dart
    var input = [
      [
        int.tryParse(txtControllerD1.text) ?? defaultValue, // or just leave it null
        ...
      ]
    ];
```